# After upgrading to spring boot 2.4.2 version getting getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.mapConnect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httpclient, webclient

After upgrading to spring boot 2.4.2 version - Webclient bean creation failing, in 2.3.8.RELEASE version same code worked.

Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'personWebClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.mapConnect(Ljava/util/function/BiFunction;)Lreactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient;

Below are the screenshot of dependency tree for both version

[image: Dependency Tree for 2.3.8 version]

[image: Dependency Tree for 2.4.2 version]